# Using CSS flexbox and grid for email templates

Tags: html, css, html-email

Can we use CSS **flexbox** and **grid** for making layouts in html email templates? And apart form  using **tables** what possible differences are there in simple html and email templates?

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-flex/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this -- can you rephrase or elaborate: "And apart form using tables what possible differences are there in simple html and email templates?" Are you asking what differences there are between coding on the web as opposed to coding in email (that would be way too general to attempt here)?

Comment: It seems I am currently looking for the same solution as you did some time ago. I need to create a HTML email template, that displays image beside text on desktop mail client. And on a mobile client it should display the image above the text.
I can only think of a flex layout, but as other already mentioned: this is not working on the default (= Desktop) Outlook client. On Android it works quite well.
Have you been able to find another solution for your problem?

Answer (score 6):

Traditionally, HTML  has been the backbone of email, so the most supported way to do email templates is to use the table tag.

is supported in 100% of today’s email clients, so no issues there. Grid, however, isn’t well supported at all, although display:flex surprisingly works in 84.85% of email clients (it actually has better support than media queries!).

However, flex’s related CSS properties (flex-wrap:, align-items:, flex-direction:, justify-content:, etc.) have terrible support — tables are the better choice.

The information is accurate as at 2022.

Source: https://designmodo.com/html-css-emails/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this website to see what tags you can or can not use: for example flex:

https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex

there are no differences between normal css and email css, the only thing is different clients. in normal situations your client is a web browser which is quite feature rich, but in emailingm your client is a email client, like gmail, which can only understand some parts of css and not all of them

my personal choice was to use MJML. its a library for handling your email templates. quite easy to learn and to use.